# Copying and pasting, removing if there's an #N/A and other criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of values, C2:E8561. In column C I have a series of descriptors, and in columns D and E I have a series of time stamps (start and end for the the descriptor. The data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, in Column C there are instances of 'Not Used' as a descriptor and an error '#N/A'. I was able to scavenge together the following code, which removes the '#N/A' errors and puts the values in Columns G, H, and I of the same worksheet.

```
Sub NoNAs()
Range("G2:I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
On Error Resume Next
Intersect(Columns("C:E"), Range("E2", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)). _
      SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow).Copy Range("G2")
End Sub
```

This works great, but it doesn't get rid of those pesky 'Not Used' instances. I've looked at possibilities that remove entire rows, but that's not what I want to do because it would damage the various functions I have populating columns A through E. Is there a way to copy the three columns, C, D and E, and remove the instances where there's either a 'Not Used' in column C or a #N/A error so that what winds up in column G through I looks something like this:

[image]

So the contents of the three columns are copied, but only if there isn't an #N/A error or if the description isn't 'Not Used'. Note that Idle Cutout Active isn't the only descriptor, there's also High Coolant Temperature among others that are possible. I'd like to keep those, just not 'Not Used'.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

So I modified the code John Coleman provided slightly. There was an issue where the variable n was set to two different things and an i was referenced elsewhere, so I set the second variable to i but I'm continuing to get a run time error when I test it. Any help with where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code in its current form:

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
Dim n As Long, i As Long
n = Range("C:C").Cells.Count
i = Cells(n, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set Source = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(n, "E"))
Set Target = Range("G2:I2")

For i = 2 To n
    If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Not Used" And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Source.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
        Source.Rows(i).Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Set Target = Target.Offset(1)
    End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = Range("C:C").Cells.Count
    n = Cells(n, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Source = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(n, "E"))
    Set Target = Range("G2:I2")

    For i = 2 To n
        If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Not Used" And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Source.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
            Source.Rows(i).Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set Target = Target.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion John, but I get an error when I try your code: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". It appears to be trying to do something, and is putting values in the three columns that I want it to but it looks like this: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/655873056f8ae6ee62bb176f8482de98.png). Interestingly, four returns is what I would expect from the data I have. It appears that what's happened is that the functions have been copied rather than the cell values which is causing the problem. Any thoughts for how to fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm... Now I'm really confused. I _think_ I managed to fix it, sort of, by locking the columns in my functions with a $, but what the code seems to be doing is returning the first four results in the column rather than filtering out the bad values. It looks like this when run: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/39b0b434e2c41f6f080a02a47d7b5cc8.png). I also still get the same run time error.

Comment: I modified the code to copy values but not formulas. You can modify the `PasteSpecial` line to copy formats as well if you want.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It works like it should now but I still get the same run time error. Do you know what's causing that? From the reading I've done, it seems like it's caused from a few different things. Here's Microsoft's [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264705.aspx) on the problem.